# creating complicated object

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create complex Character objects. Each object has a name, and for each object with the same name, they share some of the same initial data. However, there are also some bits of data that are given to the object when it's created. For example, an "Elephant" always starts out having a weight of 500, but its position is determined when it's created. Any of these values may later be changed during runtime.

I'm thinking of tackling this problem by having a bunch of code like that shown below:

```
    class CharacterStaticParameters {  
    int weight;  
    int numberOfFeet;  
    int numberOfEyes;  
}  

class CharacterDynamicParameters {  
    float positionX;  
    float positionY;  
    float velocityX;  
    float velocityY;  
}  

class Character {  
    int weight;  
    int numberOfFeet;  
    int numberOfEyes;  
    float positionX;  
    float positionY;  
    float velocityX;  
    float velocityY;  

    public Character(CharacterStaticParameters characterStaticParameters,  
        CharacterDynamicParameters characterDynamicParameters)  
    {  
        this.weight = characterStaticParameters.weight;  
        this.numberOfFeet = characterStaticParameters.numberOfFeet;  
        this.numberOfEyes = characterStaticParameters.numberOfEyes;  
        this.positionX = characterDynamicParameters.positionX;  
        this.positionY = characterDynamicParameters.positionY;  
        this.velocityX = characterDynamicParameters.velocityX;  
        this.velocityY = characterDynamicParameters.velocityY;  
    }  
}  

class StaticParameters {  
    public static final Map<String, CharacterStaticParameters> nameToParameters  
        = new HashMap<String, CharacterStaticParameters>();  
}  

//function that's somewhere else  
public Character build(String name,  
    CharacterDynamicParameters characterDynamicParameters)  
{  
    CharacterStaticParameters characterStaticParameters =  
        StaticParameters.nameToParameters.get("Elephant");  
    return new Character(characterStaticParameters,  
        characterDynamicParameters);  
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Also, is there anything that might be confusing about the way I named everything? For example, whether I should try to use words other than 'static' and 'dynamic', or a nicer word than 'parameters'?

Comment: One common way is to have an `Elephant` class.

Comment: if you have limited numbers of `CharacterStaticParameters`, you could do factories

Comment: This is unanswerable.  You haven't given the rationale or use-cases for your design, and recommendations on the names of types and variables are inherently opinion based.  You are effectively asking doe a code review ... and there's another site for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Animal{

}

class Elephant implements Animal{

}
```

Create class structure something like above, if any animal having some `initial value` then specify that value itself in class, if you want to give value to your animal then you use `constructor` to give value at time of animal creation.